# How to get all the campaigns details of the particular email from all the list in MailChimp

Tags: mailchimp

I need to get the campaigns details of the particular email from the campaigns list. Can any one please suggest the API info.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Shankar, We here at stackoverflow encourage you to try doing it yourself. And if you run into some problems, then you should post a question with information and code sample of what you tried.

Comment: @MûhámmàdYäsårK I tried to achieve by /lists/{list_id}/members/{subscriber_hash} this API. But if I have N number of lists, then i need to make N number of HTTP calls to mailchimp to achieve my goal. And it is not an good approach. That's why looking for some other alternate.